# How can you allow only members of a particular github team access to a certain resource via oauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, github-api

So I successfully setup a bare bones github oauth application flow in a Rails 4 application by following the [devise/oauth wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview).  User signs in through github, authenticates their credentials and is redirected back to a Rails app page showing all went well.

I would like to only allow certain users either of a team or a specific repo to be able to authenticate to the Rails 4 application using their github credentials.  Instead of using *scope user* as follows:

```
  config.omniauth :github, ENV['GITHUB_KEY'], ENV['GITHUB_SECRET'], callback_url: "/users/omniauth_callbacks", scope: "user:email,user:follow"
```

is it as simple as changing it to:

```
scope: read:org
```

I'm a bit unclear on the meaning of [github's scopes](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes).

EDIT:

Tetiana's answer below made me realize I misunderstood scopes.  My new understanding is as follows: Github scopes control the level of access to a user's Github data.  Once the Rails application has this access, then it's up to the Rails application to query what team a user belongs to and if they belong to a certain team, then allow them to access a Rails resource.  Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Please add more details in your question. How you decide who can authenticate to your Rails app?

Answer (score 1):

To clarify github **scopes** (and not only github. This is a **part of OAuth** consept Check this [article](http://www.forumsys.com/api-cloud-solutions/api-identity-management/oauth/?gclid=Cj0KEQiA_fy0BRCwiLaQ5-iFgpwBEiQA884sOQzFGr19TzXx4srAvjsHyW1Rnyu2aMKIiSj8PdE9P5YaAiud8P8HAQ) to know more):

Scopes do not connected with your original question. They can only specify what action can be done in your application on user's behalf.

For example, if scope is *user:email*, you can get user's github email withing your Rails application. You can send OAuth request and get this information. However, you can't get other profile information, because it's a different scope (*user*).